# IntelliJ Do not open file in single click

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

In Mac version of IntelliJ,  I see a problem with navigation.  Problem is: when I click any file using mouse or select using keyboard from Project view, it automatically opens the file in Editor.  Earlier, I've always double-clicked files in Project view to open them in Editor. How do I disable single click open? I tried to verify my KeyMap settings and nothing points to single click open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little research, here is the setting that I've changed earlier inadvertently causing the problem.

Uncheck `Autoscroll to Source` in Project view settings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I must have forgot one-click was the default with new projects and it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 5):

If the `Autoscroll to Source` answer doesn't help you, it's possible you have the newer `Enable Preview Tab` feature enabled.

Disabling this option will allow you to single-click on items without opening a new preview pane.

[image: Enable Preview Tab setting]